# Rationale behind Swift's BidirectionalCollection extension

Tags: ios, swift, collections

It is my understanding that extensions are often used on protocols to provide a default implementation. My question is about a pattern I have observed in the Swift Standard Library's protocol `BidirectionalCollection`. Consider the code below:

```
protocol BidirectionalCollection: {
    // other method requirements ...

    func distance(from start: Self.Index, to end: Self.Index) -> Int

    // other method requirements ...
}
```

followed by

```
extension BidirectionalCollection {
    // other default implementations ...

    @inlinable public func distance(from start: Self.Index, to end: Self.Index) -> Int

    // other default implementations ...
}
```

I don't understand two things about this extension:

1. Why we are able to write the method **without** a body (which I have always seen in default method implementations), and
2. What value this specific extension brings. At first glance the only difference just seems the leading `@inlinable public`. But can't protocol method requirements be prepended with those keywords anyway? What is the use of doing it in the protocol extension?

Comment: Where is this code coming from? Are you looking up the interface for `BidirectionalCollection` in Xcode (by Option-clicking on the definition)? The [`BidirectionalCollection` source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/BidirectionalCollection.swift) has the protocol requirement defined, and then a default implementation — it appears that you're just being presented these separately in Xcode because of how Xcode generates the interface, but these generated lines are not representative of the actual source code.

Comment: As already mentioned by @ItaiFerber check line 270 [code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/BidirectionalCollection.swift)

Comment: @ItaiFerber You are correct in assuming I am option-clicking in Xcode. Thanks the link you provided is helpful. I am still uncertain as to why the generated interface does not show the implementation. Is this a strategy employed by the Swift devs? If so, what is the reason behind hiding the default implementation in an internal method, that is then called by the public version of it (from line 270)?

Comment: @iOShitIScrewedUp Generated interfaces never show method implementations — they are a loose auto-generated "view" of the available APIs in a Swift type, sort of like automatically condensing the file into a C-style header. The underscored `internal` methods aren't related to this interface though; they never appear there, because they're not public API that's exposed outside of the module. (The reason for the `internal` methods are different: they allow for a private way for the stdlib to reuse/reference those methods in a few other places.)